# angularjs ng-repeat filter on static value not working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I can't figure out why the code below is not filtering just the values with unique_id of "027".  I've tried it as a string as well '027'...

JSON file:

```
[
  {
    "unique_id":"027",
    "title":"How Speed Relates to Energy",
    "state":"NY",
    "state_id":"1.S2.3a"
  }
]
```

Here my controller:

```
var abApp = angular.module('abApp', []);

abApp.factory('abData', function($http, $q) {
var deffered = $q.defer();
var data = [];
var abData = {};

abData.async = function() {
    $http.get('/data/ab_activities.json')
        .success(function(ab) {
            data = ab;
            deffered.resolve();
        });
    return deffered.promise;
};
abData.data = function() {
    return data;
};
return abData;
});


abApp.controller("abEE", function(abData, $scope) {
    var abApp = this;
    abData.async().then(function(ab) {
        abApp.alignments = abData.data();
    });

})
```

Here's my HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="abEE as ee">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="align in ee.alignments | filter:{unique_id : 027} ">
            {{align.unique_id}} - {{align.state}}, {{align.state_id}}
        </li>
    </ul>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to correct your html markup like this, as in your JSON unique_id is a string:

```
<div ng-controller="abEE as ee">
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="align in ee.alignments | filter:{unique_id : '027'} ">
        {{align.unique_id}} - {{align.state}}, {{align.state_id}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks V31, that was it... the template system I'm using was messing with the html output.